# How to control the positioning of the QSplashscreen?

Tags: c++, qt, qsplashscreen

I have an application which uses 3 splash screens in different scenarios. Problem is that I cannot seem to set a geometry or the positioning of these QSplashScreens. In fact, when the application size changes or the positioning of the application on the screen changes, the splash are displaying in random positions uncontrollably. How do I control that?

Answer (score 0):

`QSplashScreen` inherited from `QWidget` and `QWidget` have `move` function. Use this function to change location of `QSplashScreen`

For example, `splash.move(200, 200)`